# If $\mathbb{R}^n=U\cup V$ for path-connected $U,V$ then $U\cap V$ is path-connected.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose that we can write

$$
\mathbb{R}^n=U\cup V,
$$
where $U,V$ are open and path-connected. It is easy to show using Mayer-Vietoris sequence that $U\cap V$ is path-connected as well.

Is there a proof which does not use homology, ideally something just using point-set topology?

Comment: Nice question, +1. ${}$ Since the proof via the Mayer-Vietoris sequence uses the fact that $\tilde H_1(R^n)=0$, an elementary proof would use the simply-connectedness of $R^n$, so it should involve a map $D^2\to R^n$ extending the union of two paths from $x$ to $y$, one of which lies in $U$ and the other one in $V$.

Answer (score 2):

This fact is a  Corollary of the many pointed version of the Seifert-van Kampen theorem, published in 1967.

If $X= U \cup V$  is path connected, where $U,V$ are open and path connected, and  $U \cap V$ has $n$ path components,  then the fundamental group of $X$ has the free group $F$ on $n-1$ generators as a retract. See [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html) Section 8.4;   see also this  paper on the  [Phragmen-Brouwer Property](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/brouwer-cor-fin.pdf),  which gives a small correction to that section, and  further reference to the literature. This paper proves by groupoid methods that if instead $U,V,W=U \cap V$ have $n_U,n_v,n_W$ path components, then the rank of the free group $F$ is $n_W-n_U-n_V+1$.